# BizTalk Converting Chinese Characters into '????'

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

I am receiving an excel which has some Chinese characters in it and after processing sending it to CRM, but at CRM those Chinese characters are converted into '???'.

I am using UTF 16 encoding at all the schemas and pipelines. Everything else is working as expected just those Chinese characters are converting to '?'.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. A pipeline was changing the encoding of incoming files from UTF 8 to ASCII. I made some changes in the code and set the encoding as UTF8 and now everything works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).